# stm mcu with built in lcd controller

Tags: lcd, stm8

I am planning to buy an LCD display which has been customised as per my needs and it will comprise of 128 segment.

I was planning to buy a stm  MCU which will contain an LCD driver inside it while keeping the total cost of such a unit to less than $2 in a quantity of more than 50.

I came across STM8L052R8 which suggests it has built in lcd controller for 4x28 or 8x24 options.

So that means, my custom lcd should be designed such that it can be driven by this particular stm, so I'll need to choose 8 com+16 fp pins.

I'm unable to get any directions where the RAM to LCD pin mapping is kept. Any help would be welcome. Also, if my thought process is okay.

Comment: The LCD is driven via the LCD controller peripheral. The information how to use it is in the MCU reference manual.

Comment: What you mean by lcd controller peripherals. Does it require separate lcd controller?

Comment: MCU has a built-in LCD controller. The internal modules such as timers and serial ports, including the LCD controller, are all called peripherals.

Comment: I cannot find the ram to pin mapping easily. Help there pretty please..